# Promise.resolve on jqXHR ajax causes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, es6-promise

At first glance it seems you could convert a jqXHR object from jquery to an ES6 Promise. However, if the request fails, the error handler enters an infinite loop, because the parameter passed to the catch/error callback is the jqXHR itself, so the Promise is rejected with a thenable that rejects to itself, causing an infinite loop.

What is the best way to convert a jqXHR to a Promise without causing an infinite loop on error?

Two possible solutions I have thought of are to somehow get the original XMLHttpRequest and reject the promise with that on a failure, or to wrap the jqXHR in another object without a then method.

Both of these seem rather awkward though? Is there a way to suprress Promise from following then functions on the value it is resolved/rejected with? Or less desirable, a way to get the original XMLHttpRequest from a jqXHR?

Answer (score 0):

How about wrapping the `$.ajax` call with a promise?

Something like:

```
var request = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '...',
        data: { ... },
        method: 'POST',
        success: function(response) {
            resolve(response);
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            reject(errorThrown);
        }
    });
});

request.then(...).catch(...);
```

Comment: That still gets an infinite loop, because the response parameter is the jqXHR that passes itself to the error callback. And reject tries to follow thenables.

Comment: You're right! Please see me edited answer. Now the `error` function gets three arguments instead of one.